# Homogeneous deformation of isolated singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, deformation-theory, singularity-theory

Let $f\in \mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots,x_n]$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $p$ and let $F \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots,x_n,t]$ be a polynomial such that $F(x_1, \dots, x_n,0)=f$, for every $t_0$ we have that $F(x_1, \dots,x_n,t_0)$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $p$, and $\partial_t(F) \in \sqrt{\langle \partial_1(F), \dots, \partial_n(F) \rangle} \subset \mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots,x_n,t]$.

Can we conclude that $t$ is a non zero divisor of the quotient ring $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n,t]/I$, where $I = {\langle \partial_1(F), \dots, \partial_n(F), \partial_t(F) \rangle}$ ?

Note that this question is related to the question posed in [Deformation of isolated singularities and non zero divisors](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421209/deformation-of-isolated-singularities-and-non-zero-divisors) .

Comment: If $f$ has an isolated singularity at the origin, then this corresponds to a smooth hypersurface in projective space.  Then your hypothesis involving $m$ implies that the corresponding one-parameter family of hypersurfaces is constant in moduli.  This then implies that, up to a change of homogeneous coordinates to $y_i=g_i(x_1,\dots,x_n,t)$, the polynomial $F$ is $H(y_1,\dots,y_n,t)  = h(y_1,\dots ,y_n)$.  Then the quotient ring is $\mathbb{C}[t]\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C}[y_1,\dots,y_n]/\text{Jacobian}(h))$.  In this ring, the image of $t$ is a nonzerodivisor.

Comment: @JasonStarr why does this condition imply that the corresponding one-parameter family of hypersurfaces is constant in moduli?

Comment: I recommend that you look this up in a book on parameter spaces and / or deformation theory, e.g., p. 13 of "Lectures on singularities" by Michael Artin: http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr54.pdf

Comment: @JasonStarr Many thanks for your recommendation. Yet, I think there might be a problem, since if $p \geq 4$, then for a generic $g$ of homogeneous degree $p$, the deformation $f+tg$ will not be constant in moduli, and the moduli can be changed by changing $g$ accordingly.

Comment: The choice of $g$ is not generic.  If you choose $g$ so that the polynomial $F=f+tg$ satisfies your condition that $\partial_t F$ is contained in the ideal generated by the partials $\partial_i F$, then this imposes strong constraints on $g$.

Comment: @JasonStarr But under our condition, $\partial_t F$ is only in the radical of the ideal generated by $\partial_i(F)$. (This was the condition with $m$, which I restated with the radical for the sake of clarity). If $\partial_t F$ was itself an element in the ideal generated by $\partial_i(F)$, then the result would easily follow from looking at the Tjurina Algebra of $f$.  In the example I wrote above, $Jac(f)$ is a maximal ideal and the inclusion in the radical follows from Nakayama's lemma.

Comment: If the partial derivative is in the radical of the ideal, then the Kodaira-Spencer map is still identically zero.

Comment: @JasonStarr Sorry if I am being irritating, but why is this true? Isn't something like $f_t(x,y)=x^4-y^4(1+t)+x^2y^2(1-t)$ a counterexample (at least locally)? (I might be mistaken, but the fact that the partial derivative is in the radical of the ideal implies that topological triviality of the deformation, and not analytic triviality.)

Comment: I think you are right.  I was somehow thinking that $\partial_t(F)^n$ equal to zero in the versal deformation space is equivalent to "the map from the scheme to the versal deformation space is constant after passing to associated reduced analytic spaces."  That is not correct.  So I withdraw my suggestion: the suggestion only works if $\partial_t(F)$ itself equals zero in the versal deformation space, not if $\partial_t(F)^n$ equals zero.