# Cohen-Macaulyness of Milnor algebra

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, complex-geometry, singularity-theory

Denote by $R = \mathbb{C}\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ the ring of germs of analytics maps at the origin in $n$ variables and let $f \in R$ such that $Sing(V(f))=V(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1})$ as sets. In addition, assume that $V(\partial_{1}(f), \dots, \partial_{n-1}(f))=V(x_1, \dots,x_{n-1})$ as sets as well. (By "as sets" we mean without considering multiplicity, only as reduced schemes).

We know that $R/\langle \partial_{1}(f), \dots, \partial_{n-1}(f) \rangle$ is a Cohen-Macaulay ring, as it is a quotient of a Noetherian local Cohen-Macaulay ring by a regular sequence (see "Pellikaan, R. (1989). Series of isolated singularities" for proof why this sequence is regular.)

But can we conclude that $R/\langle \partial_{1}(f), \dots, \partial_{n}(f) \rangle$ is Cohen-Macaulay as well?

Comment: I already wrote a counterexample to that as an answer to the following question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421209/deformation-of-isolated-singularities-and-non-zero-divisors  As a corollary of the local flatness theorem, a morphism from a Cohen-Macaulay space to a smooth space is flat if the fiber dimension is constant.  When you apply this to your ring (under the hypothesis that it is Cohen-Macaulay) and to the ring $\mathbb{C}\{x_n\}$, you conclude injectivity of  the "multiplication by $x_n$" map.  In particular, the image of $x_n$ in your ring is not a zero divisor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just posting my comment as one answer.  Using the local flatness criterion, the ring $R/\langle \partial_1(f),\dots,\partial_n(f)\rangle$ is Cohen-Macaulay if and only if it is flat as a module over $\mathbb{C}\{x_n\}$, i.e., if and only if multiplication by $x_n$ is injective on the ring.  In the answer to a previous question, I wrote an example where multiplication by $x_n$ is not injective on the ring, i.e., I wrote an example where the image of $x_n$ is a zero divisor in the ring.  Here is the link to the previous question: [Deformation of isolated singularities and non zero divisors](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421209/deformation-of-isolated-singularities-and-non-zero-divisors)